# Python: Listening to Pusher API events

Tags: python, flask, pusher

So I've made a Flask application and I'm using it to push out data on certain events, through Pusher's [python client](https://github.com/pusher/pusher_client_python).

My challenge is to now implement a method which can listen to events from a presence channel. From what I could gather by reading the source of the python client, there isn't much scope with that package. Any other libraries I could use? Conversely, any implementations I can see and figure out how it's done? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive events via WebHooks:
http://pusher.com/docs/webhooks#presence

Or you could use the Pusher Python Client (which handles subscription functionality rather than publishing):
https://github.com/ekulyk/PythonPusherClient

The officially supported option would be to use WebHooks.